# How to get readable string from mysql with node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

When user register, i save its name in mysql (russian name in database seems like - ÐÑ€Ð¼Ð¸Ð½ÑÐ). When I take data from database with PHP and print out, it works good (show russian letters), but when user connect to node.js server (using socket.io), make mysql query (using node-mysql module) and receive data from query, then his name seems like - ÐÑ€Ð¼Ð¸Ð½ÑÐ.
How to get readable letters?

Here are some lines from my server file:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({host:'x', user:'x', password:'x', database:'x', charset:'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'});
db.connect();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    req.setEncoding("utf8");
    }).listen(8080);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: You need to get all of the systems (PHP, node, mysql) using the same encoding to interpret the data.

Comment: I edited and added some lines from my server file. There is how I set mysql module charset and server request encoding. What else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
function onRequest(request, response) {

  ...

  request.setEncoding("utf8");

  ...
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm using in the front-end:

```
function encode_utf8(s) {
  return unescape(encodeURIComponent(s));
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

So, try passing your string to

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(name));
```

Comment: Hi. I already tried this, but then node.js server dies with error:
URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)

Comment: Found this function: http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_decode/
It works partly for me (some of letters didn`t show correctly).

Comment: No, I mean to use it in the front-end, where you should show the string. Not in the nodejs part. I.e. where your html is placed.

Comment: Tried this already, same error in browser console (Uncaught URIError: URI malformed). And I need to get correct letters on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Try to debug it. If console.log data from fronted have incorrect charset, just update your socket.io script.